Removing lintel and bricks for larger wall oven
We have a brick faced wall that housed our 1950s wall oven.  The original cutout does not support modern full size 30" wall ovens, due to the cutout height requirements.  So, I would like to make the cutout larger.  The current cutout height is 25", and most of the models I've researched require between 27 - 28 5/8" cutout height.  Our width/depth is acceptable already.  Our bricks, without mortar, are 2.25" high, so removing just 1 row of bricks should support some of these oven models (or 2 rows for the other models).
I need help understanding if/how I can remove the existing brick row(s) and lintels without causing a collapse or otherwise compromising the wall.  I am fine with managing the wood cabinet changes needed.
My preference (option #1) is to remove the single row that is below the current cutout (where there is only 1 row).  The other option (option #2) is removing the 2 rows above the cutout.
To reclaim cutout height by removing the brick row(s), I would need to also remove the metal lintel supporting that row (both the bottom & top rows each have a lintel).  They are an L shape, with a bottom face, and a rear face that adds height.  The lintels extend, left to right, far enough into the adjacent bricks that I can't see where they end.  I assume they extend all way to the end of their row.  So, I'd expect that to get the lintels out, I would have to remove all the bricks behind which the lintel extends.
I'm very concerned that if I remove the bricks needed to get a lintel out, the brick face will collapse.
Is it possible to do this safely?  If so, what is the process to do this while ensuring bricks above my work don't collapse?
When I've searched online for videos of this process, in each case the video showed bricks in a running bond where there was additional support from the sides, and with a 2nd layer of bricks/mortar behind them, also adding support.


Option #1 will be the fastest(an hour or two) and safest.  That lintel is a load bearing support member and removing/replacing it will be days.  It is not only holding those two rows, but the cabinet/cupboard and the bricks above.  I would need a very good reason or command from SO to try option #2.  Option #2 is probably a professional job.

Sorry, I don't quite have an answer. But I do have a story. In 2000 I redid my kitchen except the oven. A year or two later (can't remember now) the old single oven died. I wanted a double 30" self-cleaning (both) convection (top) oven. Found a KitchenAid at half price on a Sears demo/floor sample sale, which was incredible. Got it home, got my electrician to take a look. He figured out what cable, breaker, etc. and loaned by his tools to work on the wall. Over the next few weeks I knocked out bricks, cinderblock, mortar etc. The wall was all brick face, no metal lintels (yay!)) but full

of a total mess of brick/block/etc. A LOT of dust and noise. But I got it done. My father-in-law helped with a diamond blade on a circular saw to get smooth edges left & right. My electrician came back to run the cable and hook it up and we tipped the oven in. It was quite the adventure. I still have the oven & despite needing some repairs over the years it generally works very well. Almost everyone else in the neighborhood with the same model house put in a larger oven elsewhere in the kitchen and replaced the old oven with a small cabinet/shelves. Because they were not as crazy as I was!

Have you checked to see if there's a lintel supporting the lower single row of bricks?  You may get the bricks out and find the oven still won't fit because of a lintel.

Yep, just edited the post to clarify that there are lintels at both top & bottom (so, option 1 and option 2), and added pic of the lower lintel.

Do you know how far to each side the lintels go?

No, there's no way to see the end.  I'm guessing they go to the end of their rows in both directions, for support.

The brick at the bottom is not structural. None of it is that I an see with the pictures a hand, but I believe it is all a facade, a decorative covering. Just in case it does have some structure beyond what the pictures show, and you prefer to remove the bottom, that is the best choice as well. The brick joints are lined up already with the sides and removing those few bricks can be done with a hammer and chisel and a little TLC as far as breaking bricks go.
First, remove the lower cabinet under that row of brick, it will get damaged and will be in the way for part of the process, besides it may need to be cut down in size a bit too.
Starting with the middle 2 bricks, tap the brick with a hammer, starting with light taps and getting heavier, tapping the top  until you see the surrounding area vibrate. The vibration should start the mortar cracking, if not the center brick itself. The metal lintel under these brick should have just enough give to it to allow this to happen. With the brick in the middle gone the 2 "end brick" should literally lift out, leaving the other brick that is in line with the rest intact.
If this seems to barbaric, you could use a pointing chisel to cut out the brick joints, or a grinder to do the same. It really does not need to be cut at a joint, it can be cut or broke in the middle of a brick too, for that matter.
I have done this a few times before, and it is hard to get all the details, since it comes with experience, and what I would do, since it is "core" brick, brick with hollow spaces, I will take a 16 to 20 ounce hammer and give a glancing blow from the top to crack and split the front of the brick from the middle row, then knock out the middle row, then drive the back row ever so slightly towards the lintel, not hard, there is no need to at that point, it may be loose already by this time. and remove all brick remnants.
Using a right angle grinder and a thin metal cutting blade cut the lintel out. This needs to be done with care on your part, not for the brick, but for you and your hands, eyes and face. I have learned what not to do with this type of cutting, my hands have suffered a few times doing things like this, but it is the way it needs to be done.
After all that is out of the way, you will need to build a setting platform to rest the oven on using the framing behind the brick to act as a support. FASTEN IT SECURELY!! Pilot all screw hole so no splitting occurs.
Most wall ovens I have installed are screwed to the cabinet through the sides or face flange so it does not tip out when something is set on the door when it is open. You will need to find a way to do so too, by drilling the brick or adding a bit of wood to mount the screws into once the oven is in place.

Ah, yeah I thought about cutting through the lintel to avoid having to remove the bricks in front of it, but I didn't know how to do that.  I'm going to look into that right angle grinder you mentioned.  I have a feeling I'm going to learn the hard way like you did about protecting my hands & eyes!

Gloves, the guards are a pain, limiting what you can do with it. It needs to be gripped like your hands depend on it. They do.... I do not keep a guard on mine, that's how I learned the hard way. It still off, since it is always in the way for what I do with it. There are offset flush cutting blades that will help make the cut easier with the guard on. This is an example. Look up offset metal blades. A link to Amazon will show you what you need. It doesn't have to be offset, it just makes it easier to cut in a tight inside corner.

I mean, it looks like the lintel only supports the two courses of brick above the existing opening—there's another cabinet above.  The brick appears to be simply a facade.
I guess it depends how the cabinet above is supported—is it screwed to the framing?  If so, you could simply remove the cabinet, then gently knock out the bricks and remove the lintel.  Carefully chisel out a slot in the adjacent mortar to insert the lintel into, one course above the current location (will have to grind that one brick shorter to flush it with the opening), and mortar the lintel in place.  Then place the bricks on the lintel, replace the cabinet, and install your oven. See pic below, red line shows relocated lintel.  (Jack has already mentioned securing the oven to the framing.)
YMMV if you select an oven that requires removing two courses of brick—you may need to split the difference in the courses below and above the opening.
Your wiring looks pretty old—will it work for your new oven?

Good point, I need to double check the wiring gauge & breakers.  I only checked that its 240V so far.
